# Draggable Arcs HTML5

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas

I have a radar graphics on a canvas with arcs on in it as bubbles. The bubbles are static. I need to make the bubbles draggable. The html, css and javascripts are in the following link:

Comment: Here is jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/2yRnV/1/

Comment: I don't know who put negative marking. And I don;t know what is the problem with him/her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code pattern to let the user drag your bubbles (circles).

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/WqR9F/

**First, save all the circle definitions in an array of objects:**

```
var circles=[];
circles.push({cx:10,cy:10,radius:20});
```

Then respond to mouse events:

**mousedown:**

- Save the current mouse position (lastX/lastY).
- Determine which circle(s) are under the user's mouse (see below).
- Set a flag (isDown) indicating that the user is holding the mouse down (the drag begins)

**mousemove:**

- Determine the current mouse position (mouseX/mouseY).
- Set each dragged circles new position:  cx=mouseX-lastX and cy=mouseY-lastY.
- Set lastX=mouseX & lastY=mouseY.
- Redraw the canvas.

**mouseup and mouseout:**

- Clear the isDown flag (the drag is over).

**How to determine if the mouse is inside a circle:**

```
var dx=mouseX-circles[2].cx;
var dy=mouseY-circles[2].cy;
var rr=circles[2].radius*circles[2].radius;
var isInside= (dx*dx+dy*dy <= rr);
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick I've used for something similar is to make the user drag invisible bubbles with the mouse.

The visible ones are not truly interactive, but rather follow the position of the invisible ones unless they're outside the arc.

On mouse release you then reset the invisible bubble to be positioned over the visible.